# Jquery / javascript selector for id starts with specific text and get highest value it ends in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamic text boxes that cascade down the page. When a refresh happens, I need to be able to assess how many text-Boxes the user has added to the page.

So the user will click "Add Box" and this will generate a new textbox with `id = doc0`, add another will be `id = doc1` and so on.

The issue is on refresh, I am not able to check at what increment the user reached.

I tried the starts with approach, but could not get what length was returned.

```
$('[id^=document]')
```

Ideally, on entering the page, it gets all ids starting with document and tells me what the highest value it has found proceeding it.

**EG:**

```
<div id="doc1">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc2">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc3">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc4">some elements inside</div>
```

> Answer value 4 found.

Comment: Don't use incremental `id` attributes. They are a pain to maintain - as you've seen with the issue you're facing here. Use a common class instead.

Comment: @Blawless: Rory McCrossan suggestion is good.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan And whats the best way to get the max element of that class in the way I am trying?

Comment: `$('.yourClass').length` - however if you're doing it properly you don't even need to know how many there are, you just loop through them all, if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use count if the id's are always ordered like :

```
$('[id^=doc]').length;
```

```js
console.log( $('[id^=doc]').length );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="doc1">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc2">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc3">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc4">some elements inside</div>
```

Else you could retrieve the number from the last matched element like :

```
$('[id^=doc]').last().attr('id').split('doc')[1]
```

```js
console.log( $('[id^=doc]').last().attr('id').split('doc')[1] );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="doc1">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc2">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc3">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc4">some elements inside</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return array of numbers from `id`'s with `map()` and `get()` and then use `Math.max` to return highest number.

```js
var value = Math.max(...$('[id^=doc]').map(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/));
}).get());

console.log(value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="doc1">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc2">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc10">some elements inside</div>
<div id="doc4">some elements inside</div>
```